# Как опуститься в массив на два индекса вперед при проверки вхождения

Tags: c#

у меня есть список, к примеру это `string[] zoo = {"Козел", "Овца","Осёл", "Лев", "Жираф"}`  у меня есть проверка на то, входит ли переменная `string animal = "Овца"` в список. `if(zoo.Contains(animal)){ // что то делать}`, но мне нужно, чтобы когда такой находился, я бы опускался вниз по массиву. т.е когда овца есть в списке, я хочу получить льва, когда козел - осла.

Comment: Получай индекс элемента и прибавляй 2, если выход за пределы массива то либо 1 либо 2 элемент. Индекс можно получить с помощью LINQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как пример

```
string[] zoo = {"Козел", "Овца","Осёл", "Лев", "Жираф"};
for(int i=0; i<zoo.Length-2; i++)   
    if (zoo[i] == "Овца") Console.WriteLine(zoo[i+2]);
```

Вывод

```
Лев
```

Comment: это действительно будет работать пока не выйдет за границы массива, этот код как будто написан для конкретной ситуации, а лучше было бы написать универсальный алгоритм.

Comment: Ок, сделал универсальным

Comment: а если вместо овцы написать осла, он даст жирафа?

Comment: @Tynett зачем спрашивать, вот же код - копируйте, изменяйте, проверяйте